# Bottom Bar showing above tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

The view is working fine with all other tab bar items(events, pending, explore, my profile) but for the 'more' section, the tab bar view controller when pushed to the concerned view controller shows the new bottom bar which is above the tab bar as shown in the picture.

Now I tried to set the bottom bar to none, tried to hide bottom bar in attributes inspector, nothing is working. I want help to remove this blank view regarded as the bottom bar which is showing above tab bar.

[image]

Comment: change your tablview background color as clear color as well as remove the empty cells of the tableview

Comment: I think the blank space you are talking about its your  `tableview`, change the background color of it.

Comment: Disable ViewController `Adjuest Scroll View Insets`

Comment: the empty space is not the tableview, since I have set the color of tableview to bluish gren.

Comment: try to disable `Adjuest Scroll View Insets`

Comment: Check cell property color either contentView or background color could fix this issue.

Comment: Does this happen when the keyboard appears or normally as well?

Comment: it is not the issue of the table view or its background color. as soon as the view loads , it appears two tab bars as shown in the figure

Comment: If you are pushing a view controller from TabBar Controller then you need to write this in the view controller from which you are navigating :


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! YourDestinationVC
        destinationVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
Hope it helps.

Comment: Debug View Hierarchy and find is it tableview https://sesamenotes.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/xcode-debugging-skills/

Comment: I believe your `Events viewController` embedded with `navigationController` and  you accidentally ticked `shows ToolBar` in `attributes inspector`?

Comment: @Joe if it was the case, the toolbar show be shown in all the view controllers but here I can only see it in More viewcontroller

Comment: it won't show up on all vc's.if you embedded your navigationController as a root vc of your `More view controller`.

Comment: This might apply to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47315046/removing-transculent-from-uitabbar-adds-gray-frame-above-it

Answer (score -1):

1) Write this to remove the empty cell :

```
self.tableview.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Also check the background color of cell and uitableview

Comment: its not about table view. :(