# Removing transculent from UITabBar adds gray frame above it

Tags: ios

when I set `[[UITabBar appearance] setTranslucent: false];` it adds a box with the same size just above it. I have no idea where it comes from and how to get rid of it. I think it might have something to do with how there is stuff rendering below the bar when setTranslucant is activated.

The "c" is a tableview and there are no constraints set anywhere, it's just what the SplitViewController storyboard item comes with.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, this took me **days**.
On your "most root controller", activate Extend Edges `Under Opaque Bars`. Done.

[image]